# Could I use a copy of the database directory instead of using initdb?

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have an offline Windows software that is installed locally on each user's computer. Each installation uses its own standalone PostgreSQL database. To create the database on each user's computer, the software uses the `initdb` command and then creates the tables and keys using normal SQL.

I want to avoid using the initdb command on each user's computer because sometimes this command fails (especially when the user uninstalls the `Microsoft Visual C ++ 2010 x86 Redistributable`).

I was thinking of embedding a copy of the initial database directory in the installer, so I did not have to use `initdb`. Would this work? Is there a better alternative?

Note: All users use the exact same version of PostgreSQL and the same database structure. However, they use different versions of Windows.

Comment: In theory you can, but I wouldn't recommend it. You may get into problems with privilege settings very easily, and you should make absolutely sure all copies were installed with absolutely the same version and settings. Plus, make sure nobody uninstalls the redistributables, it's not only *initdb* that needs them.

Comment: @joanolo Thanks. Unfortunately I am not able to make sure that the users don't uninstall the redistributables. Do you know if there is any documentation of which parts of PostgreSQL use the redistributables? I've noticed, that my software still works without them, connecting to the database using `pg_ctl` and running queries normally, except for when it uses the `initdb` command.

Comment: I don't really know, sorry. I guess you can't avoid your users from also *uninstalling PostgreSQL*... If I were to make lots of installations, I think I would try just to install on one machine, and *clone* the disk. Or just install on virtual machines (VirtualBox?).

Comment: I understand, but I do not make the installations. Users can download the software from our site and install it on their own computers. It's a freemium offline software, used by thousands of very simple people that don't know what VirtualBox is. I am sure that some of the users would uninstall PostgreSQL if they saw it at the Windows "Programs and Features" list. To avoid that, we use PostgreSQL's _zip archive of the binaries_, instead of installing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so - a given `initdb` will produce a datadir compatible with builds of the same `postgres`.

But.

If `initdb` fails, the rest of postgres probably will too. So you won't really be solving anything. You should instead bundle the MSVC redist in your installer.

BTW, if you install PostgreSQL bundled in an app, *please* use a non-default port, do NOT use the default port 5432. Thanks!